# Vector bundle morphism

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-bundles

Let $E \to M$ be a smooth vector bundle and let $T_x : E_x \to E_x$ be a vector space morphism for some $x \in M$.

> Can I produce a vector bundle morphism $T : E \to E$ such that $T = T_x$ when restricted to $E_x$?

Clearly if $E = M \times \mathbb R^n$ then we can define $T(m,v) = T(x,v)$ for that fixed $x$. What can we do in general?

Comment: Your example is slightly off. You only want to define the second component as $T_2(m,v)=T_2(x,v)$. The first component should be $T_1(m,v)=m$, obviously, because otherwise $T$ is not a bundle morphism. Once that is fixed, you have solved the local case. Then, use a bump function.